# Image carousel of Gridview - Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, carousel

I have GridView of the products-

[image]

When I click on the image it should open the slider with the image index but it starts the slider from the first image.

[image]

This is my Gridview builder code:

```
GridView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.data.length,
                          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 3.w,
                            childAspectRatio: 1.09,
                          ),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: (){
                                showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (
                                        BuildContext context) {
                                      return Center(
                                        child: Material(
                                          type: MaterialType.transparency,
                                          child: Container(
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              ),
                                              height: 300.h,
                                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9.w,
                                              child: ListView.builder(
                                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                                    return ClipRRect(
                                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.r),
                                                      child: Image.network(snapshot.data!.data[index].thumb.toString(), fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                                                    );
                                                  },
                                                ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    });
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                      .stretch,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      height: 135.h,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.r),
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                            image: NetworkImage(
                                                snapshot.data!.data[index].thumb.toString()
                                            ),
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      snapshot.data!.data[index].prodName,
                                      style: TextStyle(color: kblue,
                                          fontSize: 15.sp,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),),
                                  ]),
                            );
                          },
                        );
```

Have I done something wrong? I try to use carousel but it shows the same image.

Answer (score 0):

ListViews always start from the first index, however, you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) package to start from a specific index. Another method will be using PageView instead of ListView for your image carousel, then you can use PageController to move to a specific index.

NOTE: You are having index variable from two ListViews, rename anyone to avoid confusion.

Comment: I try using PageView but it still shows first index.